# Confused about the safety issue when return a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, memory-address

I know that C is passed by value. So I think that the address of a and b might be different each time that the function is called, but I am not sure....Am I right?

[image]

Comment: I mean in C language..

Comment: The addresses being different is the least of your worries.

Comment: You shouldn't post your code as image. You should post your code directly as text in the question.

Comment: This is a screen shot from my lecture's slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give an example:

```
int *x = i(1, 0);

printf("%d\n", *x);
```

This invokes undefined behavior as the function arguments have automatic storage duration and are discarded when the function returns.

Inside the function `i`, `a` and `b` objects are local to the function and their lifetime ends when the function returns.

Comment: @overloading They are not always different. Try doing some experiment. http://codepad.org/7DqFAUqn

Comment: @overloading C says nothing about that. `&a` and `&b` are invalid addresses when the function returns and you cannot assume anything about these addresses when the function returns. Inside the function they are valid addresses but you also cannot assume they will be the same with successive calls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they might be different. Try doing some experiment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *i(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b)
    return &a;
  else return &b;
}

void test(void) {
  printf("%p\n", (void*)i(1, 0));
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%p\n", (void*)i(1, 0));
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Note: do not dereference the returned pointers because they points what are already vanished on returning from the function.

Comment: I got it . Thank you!